# Adaptive icons not working in Oreo - why?

Tags: android, android-icons, adaptive-icon

I'm trying to add a custom icon from an SVG file to my Android app by right-clicking on the `res` folder -> `new` -> `Image asset`. I have selected the default options, using my SVG but I can't see the icon when I'm running the app.
I have tried to do a `clean project` before installing it and also an `invalidate cache and restart` and the result is the same.

I've also realized that `mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml` shows the default icon I'm seeing when my app is installed. This file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

when clicking on the `@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground` I get to locations to open: `drawable` and `drawable-24`. The first one shows my recently updated icon, but `drawable-24` shows the default Android icon I see when installing my app.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Anything else I have to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end, I just created the icons from a PNG instead an SVG and it works great.

Comment: 100% correct, pragmatic

Answer (score 1):

`drawable-24` folder has higher priority than `drawable`.

Api-specific resources, along with resolution-specific and language-specific are always more preferrable by Android than unspecified resources.